# IDataErrorInfo validation issue on User Controls

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, wpf-controls, idataerrorinfo

I have an entity class that implements IDataErrorInfo.  The entity class has two properties, effective date and termination date.  I have used DataAnnotations to make effective date required, as well as some custom DataAnnotations to make sure effective date comes before termination date and vise versa.

The validations are working correctly in most cases.  If I don't have a date in Effective Date, I get a red border and a tooltip that effective date is required.  If I set the termination date before the effective date, the termination date control shows up with the ErrorTemplate as expected.

Here is the problem.  If my effective date is set to be after the termination date, effective date shows up with the ErrorTemplate as expected.  However, if I go change the termination date to be after effective date, I can see in the debugger that the BindingExpression Validation attached property of the effective date no longer has an error, but the ErrorTemplate will not go away and display.

Effectively, if I update either termination date or effective date, I want it to re-validate both fields.  It seems to be doing this, but just not updating the display template accordingly.

I have WPF binding diagnostics enabled on the control and this is the information I'm seeing for the effective date binding when I update termination date to a date that should make both fields valid.

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=3778436): Got PropertyChanged event from MyEntity (hash=-46241493)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=3778436): GetValue at level 1 from MyEntity (hash=-46241493) using RuntimePropertyInfo(EffectiveDate): DateTime (hash=-1904007305)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=3778436): TransferValue - got raw value DateTime (hash=-1904007305)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=3778436): TransferValue - using final value DateTime (hash=-1904007305)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 91 : BindingExpression (hash=3778436): Update - DataErrorValidationRule (hash=29574219) failed
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=3778436): Got PropertyChanged event from MyEntity (hash=-46241493)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=3778436): GetValue at level 1 from MyEntity (hash=-46241493) using RuntimePropertyInfo(EffectiveDate): DateTime (hash=-1904007305)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=3778436): TransferValue - got raw value DateTime (hash=-1904007305)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=3778436): TransferValue - using final value DateTime (hash=-1904007305)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 91 : BindingExpression (hash=3778436): Update - DataErrorValidationRule (hash=29574219) failed
```

I have read many posts and many articles about this, but nothing I have tried has worked. I am sorry if this has been asked before, there are lots of questions about similar problems, but I'm just not sure what else to search for so thought I'd post my specific example.  Final note, I have seen some mentions of INotifyDataErrorInfo, but I can't upgrade to .NET 4.5 right now.

**Code Behind for my form**

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty MyEntityTestProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyEntityTest", typeof(MyEntity), typeof(MyForm));
    private MyEntity MyEntityTest { get { return GetValue(MyEntityTestProperty) as MyEntity; } set { SetValue(MyEntityTestProperty, value); } }

    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyEntityTest = new MyEntity();
    }
}
```

**XAML for my form**

```
<Form
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
    xmlns:z="clr-namespace:MyTest;assembly=MyTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="MyForm"
    Loaded="OnLoaded"
    >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Effective"/>
        <z:DatePickerBox Name="EffectiveDatePickerBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Date="{Binding MyEntityTest.EffectiveDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Termination"/>
        <z:DatePickerBox Name="TerminationDatePickerBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Date="{Binding MyEntityTest.TerminationDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
    </Grid>
</Form>
```

**The UserControl code behind**

```
public partial class DatePickerBox : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DatePickerBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Date", typeof(DateTime?), typeof(DatePickerBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, DateChangedCallBack));
    public DateTime? Date
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(DateProperty) as DateTime?;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(Date)) return;
            SetValue(DateProperty, value);
            FirePropertyChanged("Date");
        }
    }

    private static void DateChangedCallBack(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DatePickerBox dpb = (DatePickerBox)d;
        dpb.FirePropertyChanged("Date");
    }

    private void MainBorder_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(MainBorder, "MouseEnter", true);
    }

    private void MainBorder_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        CalendarPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void MainBorder_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(MainBorder, "MouseLeave", true);
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName == "Date")
            {
                BindingExpression be = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(this, DateProperty);

                if (be == null || be.ValidationError == null) return null;

                return (string)be.ValidationError.ErrorContent;
            }

            return Validation.GetHasError(this) ? "DatePickerBox has Error" : null;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**The UserControl XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="DatePickerBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:z="clr-namespace:MyTest">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <z:DateTimeToStringConverter x:Key="DateTimeToStringConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        <!-- We want the Validation.ErrorTemplate to show up on the TextBox, not the entire DataBoxPicker UserControl -->
        <ControlTemplate/>
    </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBox Name="DateTextBox" Margin="4,4,0,0" Date="{Binding Path=Date, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=z:DatePickerBox, AncestorLevel=1}, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
        <Border Name="MainBorder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="4,4,0,0" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" MouseEnter="MainBorder_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="MainBorder_MouseLeave" MouseLeftButtonDown="MainBorder_MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup Name="MouseStates">
                    <VisualState Name="MouseEnter">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation To="DarkGray" Duration="0:0:00.1" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState Name="MouseLeave"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <ToggleButton Name="PopupToggleButton">
                <Image Width="16" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="..\Images\calendar_16x16.png"/>
            </ToggleButton>
        </Border>
        <Popup x:Name="CalendarPopup" Margin="0,-1,0,0" IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=PopupToggleButton, Mode=TwoWay}" PopupAnimation="Fade" StaysOpen="False">
            <Calendar Margin="0,-1,0,0"
                      SelectedDate="{Binding Path=Date, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=z:DatePickerBox, AncestorLevel=1}, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                      Focusable="False" 
                      DisplayDate="{Binding Path=Date, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=z:DatePickerBox, AncestorLevel=1}, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue={x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}, TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
                <Control.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Calendar.SelectedDatesChanged">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PopupToggleButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="False"></DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame>
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Control.Triggers>
            </Calendar>
        </Popup>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**Style in my App.xaml**

Thus defines the default style for a TextBox and is where I have a trigger defined on Validation.HasError

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush>
                        <SolidColorBrush.Color>
                            <Color A="255" R="255" G="220" B="220"/>
                        </SolidColorBrush.Color>
                    </SolidColorBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**My Entity Class**

```
public class MyEntity : : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Effective Date is required")]
    [DateCompare(CompareType.LessThenOrEqualTo, "TerminationDate", ErrorMessage = "Effective Date must be the same as or come before Termination Date")]
    public virtual DateTime? EffectiveDate { get { return _effectiveDate; } set { _effectiveDate = value; FirePropertyChanged("EffectiveDate"); FirePropertyChanged("TerminationDate"); } }
    protected DateTime? _effectiveDate;

    [DateCompare(CompareType.GreatherThenOrEqualTo, "EffectiveDate",  ErrorMessage = "Termination Date must be the same as or come after Effective Date")]
    public virtual DateTime? TerminationDate { get { return _terminationDate; } set { _terminationDate = value; FirePropertyChanged("TerminationDate"); FirePropertyChanged("EffectiveDate"); } }
    protected DateTime? _terminationDate;

    #region // IDataErrorInfo Members

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            Validator.TryValidateProperty(GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null),
                                          new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = propertyName },
                                          results);

            return results.Count == 0 ? null : results.First().ErrorMessage;
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    #endregion // IDataErrorInfo Members
}
```

Comment: Dude... did you really think that anyone was going to trawl through *all* that code for you? Please read the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page from the Help Center to help you come up with a concise piece of code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: No I don't expect anyone to read all the code. I described the problem sufficiently. It was then simple to provide all the relevant pieces of code (and it really isn't that much code) in case someone wants to look at any part.  I actually did trim down this code from the much larger project it is in.  I will look at the FAQ you reference, I agree I probably could have made the example smaller, but I do feel all the pieces I posted are important to the question.

Comment: I'm just letting you know that in my experience, when users see that much code, they move to the next question. The advise was given in order to help you get an answer to your question. If your code example had been more concise, you would almost certainly have got answer(s) straight away as is customary on this website.

Comment: I get your point and I said I agree, why beat a dead horse?